# recent update broke video driver

Tags: drivers, kernel, graphics, screen, amd-graphics

2 days ago I updated my system with `apt update` and `apt upgrade`. Afterwards I was able to boot, but the screens where just black. Enabling the tag `nomodeset` in grub, thus disabling my video drivers showed me my graphic interface again, but it didn't seem to detect my screens. It only showed a zoomed in picture on my one screen, but doesn't recognize my second display at all. My second display is still black even though working (tested it with another computer)

```
-Processor-
AMD Ryzen 3 2200G with Radeon Vega Graphics

-Version-
Kernel      : Linux 5.15.0-53-generic (x86_64)
Version     : #59-Ubuntu SMP Mon Oct 17 18:53:30 UTC 2022
C Library   : GNU C Library / (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.35-0ubuntu3.1) 2.35
Distribution: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
```

I've tried installing AMD's drivers with `apt install amdgpu` or `amdgpu-install` but both ways had errors on errors with dependencies and similar stuff. After a day of work I resolved all errors, but it still didn't work. I've read that those are just the *pro* driver which have couple more features, but are for most cases not needed.

As far as I know drivers are baked in to the Kernel, including AMD's drivers. Thus this leads me to believe the Kernel doesn't support my particular *video card* yet.

So how can I resolve this? An option I have thought of are, to wait it out until the Kernel gets fixed. Can I rely on that and how long would it take? Another way could be to downgrade the Kernel. If this could work, how can I safely do so without completely damaging my system? Are there any better ways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely a known bug, see

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1996740,
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1990920

I have the same problem. I have worked around it by loading the previous kernel 5.15.0-52 in the grub menu.

I'm waiting for the revert to be available in the apt repositories before upgrading again.

Best,
Anders Søndergaard

Comment: hey thank you very much.
After restart with kernel 5.15.0-52 it didn't work. Do I have to do something afterwards like restarting any services? I am using X11.

Comment: If you removed the nomodeset flag from grub and reverted to the xserver-xorg-video-radeon drivers, then I don't know, it may be another problem. (?)

Comment: I checked it. Xorg still uses amdgpu. I gotta find a way to switch to xserver-xorg-video-radeon. thanks leading me the right way