# swap xorg video driver from amdgpu to radeon

Tags: drivers, graphics, xorg, amd-graphics, radeon

The latest Kernel update `Linux 5.15.0-53-generic` introduced a bug, breaking the radeon driver for the `AMD Ryzen 3 2200G with Radeon Vega Graphics`. It booted to a just black screen. I tried installing AMD's drivers with `apt install amdgpu` or `amdgpu-install`. After a lot of troubleshooting it didn't throw an error and installed. On reboot the drivers didn't seem to work properly. Everything looked exactly like when disabling all video drivers with `nomodeset`.

[This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1441254/recent-update-broke-video-driver) lead me to the conclusion I need to choose the older kernel in grub. But again, everything looked like when enabling `nomodeset`, even though I didn't. Further investigation showed me, that my integrated graphics actually don't need the `amdgpu` driver, but `xserver-xorg-video-radeon`.

But X11 clearly loads `amdgpu` instead of `radeon`.

```
$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'

0a:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Raven Ridge [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series] (rev c8)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Radeon RX Vega 11
    Kernel modules: amdgpu
```

So I probably configured the wrong drivers somehow, instead of fixing my initial problem.

```
-Processor-
AMD Ryzen 3 2200G with Radeon Vega Graphics

-Version-
Kernel      : Linux 5.15.0-53-generic (x86_64)
Version     : #59-Ubuntu SMP Mon Oct 17 18:53:30 UTC 2022
C Library   : GNU C Library / (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.35-0ubuntu3.1) 2.35
Distribution: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

-Display-
Resolution  : 1024x768 pixels
Vendor      : The X.Org Foundation
Version     : 1.21.1.3
Current Display Name: :1

-Monitors-
Monitor 0   : 1024x768 pixels

-OpenGL-
Vendor      : (Unknown)
Renderer    : (Unknown)
Version     : (Unknown)
Direct Rendering: No
```

Am I right to assume I need to somehow change the video driver of my xserver? And if so, how can I safely do so? Currently everything looks like no graphics driver have been loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This post lead me to the conclusion I need to choose the older kernel in grub.

This is the one of the two valid solutions.

You should report the bug to Canonical [if it hasn't reported already](https://bugs.launchpad.net/), meanwhile use the older kernel (by freezing upgrades via Synaptic) and wait until an updated kernel that works on your system is ready.

You can try a [PPA mainline kernel](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/) though.

The second valid solution is installing amdgpu-pro from AMD, which is an alternate driver. However I would not recommend it, since a lot of users end up having trouble with it, and if you're not fluent with the CLI, it gets hard to restore a graphical interface if things go wrong.

It's hit or miss.

### radeon vs amdgpu

You can't use the `radeon` driver for your GPU. That driver is an older one written to work with Radeon HD 2000-6000 series and first-generation GCN cards (e.g. Radeon HD 7770, Radeon R9 280, etc).

The `amdgpu` driver is a newer driver that works with all GCN and RDNA chips.

Your Vega chip is the last GPU with GCN architecture, and it won't work with `radeon`. Trying to force it could either not work or lead to HW damage.

### Driver architecture explanation

It seems you are confused so I'll explain what's going on: Your AMD drivers in Linux have 2 components: kernel space and user space.

Kernel-space drivers are shipped alongside with the kernel. When a bug is introduced, they're tied to the kernel version. Kernel bugs like these get often fixed quickly upstream (in days or weeks), but Ubuntu takes its time (often a few months) due to how backporting changes from upstream kernel works in Ubuntu.

From what you are mentioning, this is the cause of the problem.

User-space drivers are shipped separately with Mesa and X11 packages. Since the problem lies in the Kernel section of the drivers, messing with these packages won't fix it and you risk breaking up something by accident.

## Update

OK from your reply you said that you downgraded your kernel and it still didn't work.

First, make sure you're actually downgraded via:

```bash
uname -r
```

You can try multiple Kernel versions by going to GRUB -> `Advanced options for Ubuntu` and start selecting the other versions.

OK, so assuming that won't work the next thing to try/suspect:

### Your Xorg logs

Post the contents of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`. It may contain valuable info.

Since you boot to a black screen, you can try switching to tty (Ctrl + Alt + F2)

If the keyboard is unresponsive, then boot into safe mode, install openssh-server, reboot into normal node, and control your computer from a 2nd computer.

### Make sure amdgpu module is loaded

Run:

```bash
lsmod | grep amdgpu
```

It should have hits and amdgpu should be in use.

If it's not there then run:

```bash
sudo modprobe amdgpu
```

If that fails, check `dmesg`.

### Restart your DM

Sometimes there is a race condition in loading your drivers, and the real problem is that your DM started before your GPU drivers were ready. So the DM crashed.

I've personally run into this problem: Half of the time, at random, I would boot into a black screen and the keyboard would be dead. However the following command from an SSH session would restore my computer.

I don't know which DM you use so one of these commands should be the one for you:

```bash
sudo service lightdm restart
sudo service gdm3 restart
sudo service sddm restart
```

### Add amdgpu firmware to initramfs so it's available early

This is a fix to the mentioned race condition in the previous item.

Run the following:

```bash
echo "amdgpu" | sudo tee --append /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)
```

If done properly then to check it worked, running:

```bash
lsinitramfs /boot/initrd.img-$(uname -r) | grep amdgpu
```

Should return multiple hits (where there previously should be none).

Then reboot and cross finger things work.

You can undo this change by removing the amdgpu line from `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules` and running `update-initramfs` again

### Try another firmware package

The package [linux-firmware](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/linux-firmware) provides all the firmware blobs for your HW, including AMD's GPUs.

An older version may fix your problems, or a newer one.

You can also try the latest ones from https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git

You can rollback the latest ones from git via `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-firmware` (since they are all files that go into `/lib/firmware`)

### Check from a LiveUSB

If you stil are unable to fix it; create a LiveUSB and boot from there: You may be tempted to reinstall Ubuntu (a valid option).

If the LiveUSB shows the same problem, you may have to consider HW damage (your iGPU is malfunctioning, or the cable to your monitor is bad, the cable is loose, or your monitor is bad, or the connector/port is). If this is the case, try Windows as well.

Comment: The thing is, I actually already downgraded my kernel and it still doesn't work. I installed like stated above some stuff from amd. Then the downgrading didn't solve anything. Trying to undo the messing around with amd stuff actually uninstalled the core of xserver, but it wasn't to bad to fix.  
Which step would you advice me to take?

Comment: Updated my reply with more things for you to try. Good luck!

Comment: running `sudo modprobe amdgpu` perfectly worked. If thats the case for anyone stumbling onto this, and you use SystemD as init system, follow this Thread: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71064/systemd-automate-modprobe-command-at-boot-time?newreg=1b1d47c18fae4fc6ac9b24e127983dd3